# Elastic search regexp query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to find documents on my elastic cluster where field looks like `abc/v1/123123`

So, i have tried following lucene expressions:
`field: /abc/v1/<0-9>{6}/` - it found separated entries `abc` or `v1` or `123456`. Seems `/` here is working like operator OR. But i need documents where these findings stuck together
Adding the escape 
`field: /abc\/v1\/<0-9>{6}/` - No results match your search criteria

I am able to find my documents using this `field: "abc/v1/*/"`
But I would like to filter entries with 6 digits in the end.

Comment: Please provide the query what you ahve tried and also provide the index mapping.